# CoreData doesn't delete records in autogenerated relationship table

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, core-data

CoreData / SQLite question here...

If you create two entities in XCode, **TableA** and **TableB**, and create a many-to-many relationship between them, CoreData will create a 3rd sqlite table at runtime called "**Z_TableAToTableB**" to manage the relationship between the two.

However, I notice that when I delete ALL rows in TableA and TableB, the records in Z_TableAToTableB remain there for some time. They are not immediately deleted.

Is this by design? It's really frustrating and causing concurrency issues in my app. I also have cascading delete set up between TableA and TableB, so deleting rows from one will delete rows from the other, but the rows in the 3rd table are never deleted.

How can I delete the records in **ZTableAToTableB**?

UPDATE:

Here is how my tables are set up. For the sake of argument, let's focus just on Project-Segment relationship.  Notice the many-to-many relationship between the two tables. Occasionally, I need to *delete **ALL** records* from the Project table and refresh it with some new data. But when I do this, the PK of the Project table starts back at 1 again. *(This is especially true when a user upgrades from the Old version of my app to the New version of my app, but I digress)* This would be fine by me, IF the relationship records in Z_ProjectToSegment were getting deleted, but they aren't. This results in false relationships between Project-Segment.

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Can you show the delete code? The relationships between the entities should be deleted once each object is deleted and the managed object context is saved. Also, could the object graph have become out-of-sync during development and so left some orphaned records behind?

Answer (score 3):

My guess was going to be that you had your deletion rule wrong, but you mentioned that being set to cascade. Internally, Core Data may round old join tables up and delete them in batches later on, it may never delete them... Who knows.

Ultimately, it's not something we're supposed to worry about, and even if we do, there's nothing we can do about it (you really, really don't want to root around and make changes in a Core Data sqlite file without its permission).

As for it 'causing concurrency issues in your app', I find that exceedingly unlikely, and we'd need a more specific example.

Comment: My app requires users to "synch" their data periodically with our server, to support offline use.  I do this with the following algorithm:

1) Delete all records in Table A and Table B
2) Commit
3) Download new data
4) Insert new data into Table A and Table B, and create relationships between the rows

The concurrency issues in my app arise because, if I delete all records in TableA, and commit the changes to the NSManagedObjectContext, the Primary Key of TableA is starting back at 1. This results in a false relationship if Z_TableAToTableB still contains a between TableA id=1 and TableB id=N.

Comment: I find that if I remove step 2 [managedObjectContext save:nil], and save it for the end after all my 'new' records are inserted, the PK of Table A doesn't start back at 1. But I find this to be a silly workaround. I should be able to call [managedObjectContext save:nil] whenever I want without this sort of repercussion.

Comment: Someone has suggested that, prior to delete, I break the relationship between the two tables by looping through the ProjectToSegment array on each Project, calling removeObject: on each item, *then* deleting the entities. I will try this and report back my findings.

Comment: It sounds like your syncing strategy relies on you being able to essentially load the entire object graph into memory, deleting them all at the same time, then just re-importing what will almost always be the same exact data from the server. If that's accurate and your only goal is offline support, this is a really roundabout way to accomplish that, and I'd recommend reading up on sync theory a little more. Find-or-create is part of a good syncing strategy; destroy-then-recreate is not.

Comment: You're right about that.  I unfortunately inherited this from the contractor that originally wrote it (read: slapped together), and I haven't had the luxury of time to pay off technical debt & completely refactor the sync algorithm (read: features, features, features!). I'm just trying to work with what I was given.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work around this problem by waiting until the very end of my Sync operation to save the MOC..

The sync algorithm WAS:

- 1) Delete all records (background thread)
- 2) Save the background MOC and merge with UI-thread MOC.
- 3) Download & insert new records (background thread)
- 4) Save the background MOC and merge with UI-thread MOC.

NOW the algorithm is....

- 1) Delete all records (background thread)
- 2) Download & insert new records (background thread)
- 3) Save the background MOC and merge with UI-thread MOC.

By waiting until the very end to "save" the MOC, the table is never truly empty and thus I successfully prevent CoreData from resetting the id PK to 1.

I still worry that there is no way to instruct CoreData to "clean up" the relationship tables. It seems to clean it up whenever it feels like it. But for now this solution is working for us until we figure out a better sync algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

I have found out if I have toMany relationships between two objects Ordered, the tables are never cleaned. If I set as not ordered, after deleting both objects the table is cleaned also.

It looks to me that ordered relationships has some issue cleaning up the order table.

Comment: Can you explain more? As you can see in my screenshots, neither table is set to Ordered. When I delete the contents of both tables, the 3rd table created at runtime isn't (immediately) cleaned. It eventually is cleaned, but it seems to be unpredictable when this occurs.